# Python-attribute error with bluebooth

Tags: python, bluetooth

I use `google-voice-kit` with raspberry pi 3. I try to change the code to connect to bluetooth. The code is:

```
import aiy.audio
import aiy.cloudspeech
import aiy.voicehat
#import bluetooth


def main():
recognizer = aiy.cloudspeech.get_recognizer()
recognizer.expect_phrase('turn off the light')
recognizer.expect_phrase('turn on the light')
recognizer.expect_phrase('blink')

button = aiy.voicehat.get_button()
led = aiy.voicehat.get_led()

#bd_addr = "E0:31:4B:2C:C6:4E"
#port = 1
#sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
#sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
aiy.audio.get_recorder().start()

while True:
    print('Press the button and speak')
    button.wait_for_press()
    print('Listening...')
    text = recognizer.recognize()
    if text is None:
        print('Sorry, I did not hear you.')
    else:
        print('You said "', text, '"')
        if 'turn on the light' in text:
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.ON)
            #sock.sent([0x00,0xFF,0x01,0x03,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF])
            #sock.close()
        elif 'turn off the light' in text:
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.OFF)
        elif 'go' in text:
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.BLINK)
            sock.sent([0x00,0xFF,0x01,0x03,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF])
        elif 'goodbye' in text:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code which starts with "#" is what I added.

The error is: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BluetoothSocket'`

I installed the bluetooth and used `chmod` to change its permissions but it still gives the error. The name of this code is `cloudspeech_demo.py`. I am certain that i don't have any file which name is the same as this.

Comment: Where you able to import bluetooth successfully ? If yes, then did you tried checking for BluetoothSocket manually in the bluetooth package?

Comment: And check your project for files and folders named `bluetooth` that would cause a name clash on import.

Comment: I write another code in the same folder.This code just test the bluetooth function.The cod is:import bluetooth
def main():
    bd_addr = "E0:31:4B:2C:C6:4E"
    port = 1
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
    sock.sent([0x00,0xFF,0x01,0x03,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF])
    sock.close()

Comment: I write another code in the same folder.This code just test the bluetooth function and the code doesn't have this error.so i think i import the bluetooth is successfully.I use dir(bluetooth) to check BluetoothSocket and it's really in the bluetooth package.i don't have files or folder named bluetooth.